# How to convert dict or list to string in ansible

Tags: json, ansible

## play:

```
  - set_fact:
      irules: "{{ rule | json_query('[*].definition') }}"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ irules }}"
```

## output:

```
"msg": [
    "when HTTP_REQUEST {\n    switch -glob [HTTP::uri] {\n    \"*HAC*\" { pool char.hr.cal.ed.ABC.pool }\n        \n     }\n}"
]
```

}

I'm expecting output to be in below format.

## Expected output:

```
"when HTTP_REQUEST {
     switch -glob [HTTP::uri] {
     "*HAC*" { pool char.hr.cal.ed.ABC.pool }   
 }
```

I have tried parsing "from_json" to the above play and ended up with the error:

```
"({{ rule | json_query('[*].definition') | from_json }}): the JSON object must be str, bytes or ``bytearray, not 'list'"}"
```

is there a way to convert list to string in ansibe?
if not, any other suggestions would be appreciated to achieve "Expected output"`

Comment: Can you kindly point exactly where you see a yaml or json representation of a list/dict in the actual content of the `definition` variable ? At best from what I see, you can split that string on new lines to output it as a list of lines which should be more readable: `msg: "{{ irules.split('\n') }}"`. Unless your find a module/filter able bo parse the particular language/representation.

Comment: Thank you for your response 
{
    "msg": [
        {
            "definition": "when HTTP_REQUEST {\n    switch -glob [HTTP::uri] {\n    \"*HAC*\" { pool char.hr.cal.ed.HAC.pool }\n        \n     }\n}",
            
    ]
}

Comment: I tried to split  with msg: "{{ irules.split('\n') }}" and ended up with error.
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'split'\n\n

Comment: Ok got it. then it should be `msg: "{{ irules[0].split('\n') }}"`.... or you would have to parse every list element with a filter which understands that language/representation.

Answer (score 0):

Module `debug` of Ansible cannot print carriage return. It always escape them (converting them into `\n`). That's why you have many `\n` in your debug print msg.

The only option I know to output multiline variable is to use the `pause` module :

```
- pause:
    seconds: 1
    prompt: "{{ irules[0] }}"
```

More detailled answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188167/ansible-print-message-debug-msg-line1-n-var2-n-line3-with-var3#answer-56391268) can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot jean. I'm able to print in expected format. Is there a way to store that printed content in variable. I have to copy that content to a file and add few extra lines to that file and have to apply that configuration content to firewall.  Please let me now if you need any info

Comment: Your variable content is already fine. It contains carriage returns as you'd like. You can already write the variable content in a file.

Comment: I have used split  msg: "{{ irules[0].split('\n') }}" and copied to a file and content stored in a file is:  ["when HTTP_REQUEST {", "    switch -glob [HTTP::uri] {", "    \"*HAC*\" { pool char.hr.cal.ed.HAC.pool }", "        ", "     }", "}"]

I would like to remove characters  [ and  " and \  from the file and the format it to similar to expected output..